# to infinitive vs gerund, which one is more widely used in SPOKEN language?

Tags: spoken-english, infinitive-vs-gerund

A man and a woman is sitting on the bench, and the guy asks her,

> "You like **being** here with me too, right?"
>
> "You like **to be** here with me too, right?"

which one is more natural and widely used when *speaking* English?
I don't know why, but the first one (being) feels a bit unnatural and I'm not sure if natives will actually say like that in real life.

In real life when natives speak with each other, which one between infinitve and gerund is more commonly used? It depends on the context?

Or if this whole expression "You like ~ here with me too, right?" is not likely used, is there any other expression that has the same meaning?

Comment: Your sense that **being** is "a bit unnatural" is more than a bit wrong. It is probably the more common of the two, though they mean slightly different things, so comparing their frequency would be misleading.

Comment: **Being** is definitely the more common in spoken English.  **To be** could be used for something similar but not usually in that exact context (they are already there together).  If they were not already in the same room, you could say "you would like to be here with me too, right?" but that is quite a different circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native American-English speaker, I would definitely say, "You like being here with me too, right?" I think it would sound very odd to use "to be." These generalizations hold for writing as well. Using "to be" in speech or writing in this context would show that you aren't a native speaker.

"To be" has more of a future or hypothetical meaning in this context, I think. If I were talking to someone on the phone, I might say, "You would like to be here with me, right?"